# regex alphanumeric + space + 3 chars in php and if possible javascript

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i need to find the good regex to work in php and javascript, 
the accepted chars are :

```
  é  è ' space and alphanumeric
```

i tried this :

`if(!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+([\\s]{1}[a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9])+$/i", $name))`

If you have the solution in php and javascript it will a perfect world :)

thanks for help

Comment: This is an ontopic answerable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unicode properties:

```
preg_match("/^[\pL\pN\s']+$/u", $name)
```

`\pL` stands for any letter
`\pN` stands for any number

Comment: it doesn't work with é and è , i 'm jsut try it ; i need é and è

Comment: @albator: Sorry, add the `u` modifier at the end. See my edit. It will work with any letters like:`é è ç à ù ...`

Comment: @albator this regex matches all letters from any language like arabic too `ف ع ت ن`

Comment: @M42 while it doesn't cover the answer properly, yes.

Answer (score 3):

So you should go with the corresponding regex:

```
^[[:alnum:]éè ]+$
```

*Explanation:*

```
^                      # start of string
    [                  # match these characters
        [:alnum:]      # all alphanumeric chars
        é              # é letter
        è              # è letter
                       # a space
    ]                  # end of char group
    +                  # one or more sequence of these characters
$                      # end of string
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/mP2nV1)

Comment: it works but it allow @ and so on, i just need letters and numbers and one space and spécial char é and è

Comment: @albator no, it doesn't allow special characters like `@`. go to the live demo and add your test string to the left box and check. I did it already

Comment: @albator I also improved the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex could probably be distilled down to

```
 #  ^[a-zA-Z0-9éè'](?:[ ]?[a-zA-Z0-9éè']+)*$     

 ^ 
 [a-zA-Z0-9éè'] 
 (?: [ ]? [a-zA-Z0-9éè']+ )*
 $
```